# Connect two sockets ( client & server ) using python and Typscript

Tags: python-3.x, angular, sockets, socket.io

**Issue**

I'm having an issue connecting two sockets. The relationship is a client and server (single connection).

**What I Have**

I am able to successfully run my server using python3 and also am successfully able to host my Angular application that connects the socket but when I try to emit an event or connect from my Angular code I get  400 error during the handshake the error on the python server side looks like this

**The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)**

**What I want to be able to do**
Connect to the server and have it send a json payload and later video feed.

Python3 code

```
import eventlet
import socketio

sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins='*')

app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, static_files={
    '/': {'content_type': 'text/html', 'filename': 'index.html'}
})


@sio.on('sensorframe')
def message(sid, data):
    print('message ', data)

@sio.event
def controller(command: str):
    print(command)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('127.0.0.1', 8010)), app)
```

**python-socketio version = 5.0.4**

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

export class GuagesComponent implements OnInit {
  private sensorframe: object;
  public socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

  constructor(
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private _socketService: SocketsService
  ) {
    this.socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8010', {
      reconnection: true,
      reconnectionDelay: 5000,
      reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
      reconnectionAttempts:  5,
      transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket', 'xhr-polling'],

    });
    console.log(io.protocol); // 4
  }

  private eventFire(): void {
   this.socket.emit('controller', 'data from client');
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

**LOG OUTPUT**

```
python3 server.py 
(149348) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:8010
(149348) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 51348)
The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2021 17:58:38] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 195 0.000308
(149348) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 51392)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came down to version. Socket IO client was fine on the front end but I had to use this version for python3

engineio==3.13.2 and python-socketio==4.6.0